# why cant i use the code in output' on vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So i just formatted my pc, i want to use ctrl+alt+n to run a code in the output.
The hotkey does nothing now and when i go to the play button it just lets me run python file nothing else.

tried changing language pack on windows, tried reinstalling and using an older version, tried different interpreters aso

Comment: check out : https://superuser.com/questions/1501391/why-did-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-alt-n-stop-working-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is the shortcut key for [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to run the code, so please check if you have this extension installed first. Then you can check if the shortcut key binding is changed as follows.

[image]

However, it is still recommended that you use the official extension **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)** to execute python scripts.